# Can a real object also be considered as a real image if the direction of rays were to be reversed?

Tags: reflection, geometric-optics, mirror-symmetry

I came across the concept in a book wherein a real object is classified as a body that emits diverging beams of light; whereas the virtual objects are a point or a collection of point where the light rays appear to meet (a set of converging beams). Let us consider a set of converging beam incident on a plane mirror(which by very definition are virtual objects!). After reflecting off the mirror, it converges to meet at a point in a real space (thus a real image is obtained).

If we were to reverse the path of light, wouldn’t it become a typical case of image formation in a plane mirror (where an object placed before the plane mirror produces a virtual image)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.